# Windows server 2016 VPS blocking connection even with firewall disabled

Tags: networking, firewall, port-forwarding, windows-server, vps

I have a windows server 2016 VPS and I want to open ports on it. I went on windows firewall and created an inbound rule to allow tcp connections to the specified port. I even completely disabled the firewall. Still, when trying to access my ports I cannot connect to them.

To test, I created a nodejs project and installed express.js and served it on port 200. I then allowed port 200 in my firewall. When I entered the ip address of my vps with the port (e.g. 123.123.1.12:200) into Chrome or Postman, I just get an error saying it cannot connect to the my vps.

I contacted the company I bought the vps from and they explained that they do not block any ports or connections to or from the servers.

Is there some setting I must adjust on windows server to allow connections?

Edit:
I tried sending a GET request to my expressjs port (200) on Postman and got the result:
`Error: connect ETIMEDOUT <my vps ip>:200`

Also, another thing to note, I have a SQL Server running on my vps to which I am fully capable of connecting to. I simply setup an inbound rule for the port that I chose for the SQL Server and it worked.

Comment: Do you have any other security product installed on the server?

Comment: @harrymc, No, there are no antiviruses or anything of the sort

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when connecting? Include all details including the URL used and the error code.

Comment: @harrymc, I will edit original question

Comment: @harrymc, I edited.

Comment: Can you ping the server? Is anything listening on port 200?

Comment: @harrymc, Yes, pinging the server works perfectly fine. On port 200 I have a nodejs project running expressjs which just sends back "Hello" in plaintext as a response for any GET requests.

Comment: Have you tested that the project works locally? Test also using some service ([example](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2)) to see if the port is truly open and has a listener.

Comment: @harrymc, Yes. When accessing localhost:200 on the vps it works. I have also tested this app on other ports as well. I also tried setting up a postgres server on the vps on port 5432 to which I also cannot connect.